# How to add input field value to Users in Wordpress Dashboard

Tags: php, html, dashboard

I've got a request where the client would like to store provided emails in the WordPress Dashboard so they can access them for marketing.

I've added an email input field like so:

```
<div class="form-group form-group50">
            <p for="email">Enter your email</p>
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required>
</div>
```

I've been scouring the web to find an answer and I tried the following:

```
if ( isset( $_POST['email'] ) ) {
  $email = sanitize_text_field( wp_unslash( $_POST['email'] ) );
  if ( $email ) {
      wp_insert_post(
          array(
              'post_title'  => $email,
              'post_type'   => 'users',
              'post_status' => 'publish', /* Or "draft", if required */
          )       
      );
  }
}
```

But this does not do anything. I am assuming because nothing could be triggering this function.

The form itself is a type of Calculator, so instead of submitting the form, it calls a custom jQuery function by using the id #calculator.

I hope this makes sense, but I am also limited on what I can share code wise.

To summarise:
The value of the email field needs to be captured and stored within Users on Wordpress Dashboard.